# What is the practical usages of MessagePorts in electron Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application, webapi

what is the practical usages of MessagePorts in electron Js? why we need this? instead can't we use ipcRenderer.invoke? I can't see any practical usages of MessagePorts. It's just data transfering between main process and renderer process like ipcRenderer.invoke and ipcMain.handle. **Can you tell me a practical problem that can only be solved with MessagePort and can't be solve by ipcRenderer.invoke and ipcMain.handle?**

Comment: MessagePorts are from the web standards. So for one thing, they allow non-electron scripts that use them to run correctly?

Comment: non-electron script means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself.
basically in official documentation they have given three usages examples of Channel Messaging API.

[image]

We can read those example to understand. (First time I didn't saw it so that I got confused)

1. [Worker process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/message-ports#worker-process)
2. [Reply streams](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/message-ports#reply-streams)
3. [Communicating directly between the main process and the main world of a context-isolated page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/message-ports#communicating-directly-between-the-main-process-and-the-main-world-of-a-context-isolated-page)